# OpenGL ES C++ engine or framework

Tags: opengl-es

I am looking for OpenGL (ES) help library that does following things.
Load texture from PNG, TGA and PVRTC file
Load model from some 3d format file e.g. wavefront .obj

Could you recommend such library?

It should be C++ not Objective-c

I already have Marmalade (AirPlay) engine and I used its GX library. GX has few bugs and I wish to use plain OpenGL ES in marmalade. So I am looking for some help classes that will load resources.